# Corona SDK OpenSSL plugin issue

Tags: lua, openssl, coronasdk

I have the problem including OpenSSL plugin in my corona project.

On this line

`local openssl = require "plugin.openssl"`

project crashes with error:

```
> module 'plugin_openssl' not found:resource (plugin_openssl.lu) does
> not exist in archive no field package.preload['plugin_openssl'] no
> file '/Users/Apple/Library/Application
> Support/Corona/Simulator/Plugins/plugin_openssl.lua' no file
> '/Users/Apple/Library/Application
> Support/luaglider2/dev/ProjectBuilds/___________(Builds)/___________(default)/___________/plugin_openssl.lua' no file '/Applications/CoronaSDK/Corona
> Simulator.app/Contents/Resources/plugin_openssl.lua' no file
> '/Users/Apple/Library/Application
> Support/Corona/Simulator/Plugins/plugin_openssl.dylib' no file
> './plugin_openssl.dylib' no file '/Applications/CoronaSDK/Corona
> Simulator.app/Contents/Resources/plugin_openssl.dylib'
```

In my `build.settings`:

```
plugins = {
     ["plugin.openssl"] = {publisherId = "com.coronalabs"},
},
```

Can anybody encounter with this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Are you a pro or enterprise subscriber?  What build of Corona SDK are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

At the start of app Corona need to download plugin. But on my workplace proxy blocked downloading.

Answer (score 0):

This is old question, but currently OpenSSL plugin may require VS2013 x86 redistributable https://aka.ms/highdpimfc2013x86enu to work. This will help if your error says `error loading 'plugin_openssl' from file '....\plugin_openssl.dll'. Erro says that it found the dll, but can't load it. Redist would solve the issue.